# How to transfer files from/to an Android device with ADB via GUI?

Tags: software-recommendation, nautilus, android, files, transfer

Do you know if there is an Ubuntu program (possibly a Nautilus plugin) to transfer files from/to an Android device?

What is my mind is a program which does `adb push`, `adb pull`, and `adb shell ls` in the background and has a GUI.

Note that ADB allows for broader filesystem access than MTP and UMS.